# Lookahead function

Tags: php, function, variables, regex-lookarounds

I have this

```
87||2|#88||4|#89|
```

or

```
87||1|#88||3|#89|
```

or

```
95||1|#88||1|#89|
```

or other variables data. Every times that there is a `...|#88||number|...)`, I need to capture the "number" and "print" it.

Through some of the suggestions received, I wrote this, but the result is still not correct.

```
function caratteristiche1($property_bedrooms) {
    $new = preg_match("/\|88\|\|(\d+?)\b/", $property_bedrooms);
    print_r($new);
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Your regex looks right (or on the right track).  What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call an overloaded version of `preg_match()` which accepts an array containing the matches as a third parameter.  The number you matched (in parentheses) will be available in the *second* position of the `$results` array.  Just access this value and you should be good to go:

```
function caratteristiche1($property_bedrooms) {
    $new = preg_match("/\|#88\|\|(\d+)/", $property_bedrooms, $results);
    print_r($results[1]);
}
```

By the way, `$results[0]` contains the full input string.

Click the link below if you want to test the working regex.

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aZ2oH0/1)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer! I tried both ($results[0]) and ($results[1]) but it reports a synthax error caused by (0) and (1). I tried even with print_r($results); but it reports Array (). What do right now? Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks Tim!
Your Regex is good. The right function is:

```
function caratteristiche1($property_bedrooms) {
$new = preg_match('/\\|#88\\|\\|(\\d+)/', $property_bedrooms, $results);
print_r($results[1]);
}
```

Thanks for your time!